# wpdb->prepare and mysql UPDATE - how is it done?

Tags: plugin-development, database, wpdb

Trying to set a 'removed' date time in a plugin query but I'm not sure how to use UPDATE SET with $wpdb->prepare.

Here's my query:

```
$cur_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');        
$rows_affected = $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare("
        UPDATE $table
        SET ( removed, post_id, user_id, status )
        VALUES ( %s, %d, %d, %d )
    "),
    array($cur_date, $postid, $userid, 0)
));
```

Can I set up UPDATE like this using $wpdb? Very new to self crafted DB queries.

If not, how should/can I accomplish this?

Thanx in advance!

EDIT ---------------------------------------------------

New code:

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'ds_entry_swoons';
$cur_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s'); 
$rows_affected = $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare("
        UPDATE {$table}
        SET  removed = %s, post_id = %d, user_id = %d, swoon_status = %d
        WHERE post_id = $postid AND user_id = $userid;",
        $cur_date, $postid, $userid, 0
    )
);
```

Comment: Just use wpdb's internal update function.  It handles sanitization for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I sort of fixed your query. It needs a table and a WHERE condition to prevent changing all rows. Even a LIMIT 1 at the end won't hurt.

```
$rows_affected = $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "UPDATE {$table} SET removed = %s, post_id = %d, user_id = %d, status = %d;",
        $cur_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $postid, $userid, 0
    ) // $wpdb->prepare
); // $wpdb->query
```

Just add the WHERE... in the MySQL query. Proper use of prepare is:

```
$wpdb->prepare($format, $arg1, $arg2, ...); // just like printf()
```

Comment: Actually, LIMIT 1 is very dangerous with UPDATE and DELETE statements. This is particularly true if the database is a Master in MySQL Replication setup because there is no guarantee the order of UPDATE/DELETE on the Slave. Warnings about this will be posted in the Master's MySQL error log. Other than that, your answer is essentially correct once @dkmojo adds the WHERE clause. +1 !!!

Comment: If you target a primary key ID or a unique key combo... why would it be dangerous?

Comment: That's would be the only exception. Nonunique keys would be a different story. MySQL may still post warnings in the error log either way.

Comment: I actually wrote a post about that in the DBA StackExchange : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery/1384#1384. It has to do with the way MySQL Optimizer performs query transformations under the hood.

Comment: True but this should be a conscious decision. If you know you plan to update a single record, AFAIK, it's good practice to impose the LIMIT 1. If you have a variable number of records to update, never use the LIMIT as default sorting is... unsorted :)

Comment: There are bugs reports in mysql website for 4.0 (closed : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1024) and 5.1 (patch applied a year ago : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42415) about using UPDATE/DELETE with LIMIT. Even with all bugs fixes around LIMIT, MySQL Replication for the Slave can still be victimized. I learned about this from just the order of SELECTed rows : http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6051/877.

Comment: Using LIMIT may also involve temp tables if the query warrants it. All temp tables generated by queries are, by nature, unsorted as you commented on before. LIMIT waltzes through such temp tables making its order of execution and access different from Master to Slave.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth feedback! I added the WHERE clause and added my edited code above. But am unsure of what the '{}' around $table are for or if they are needed. I have other queries that do not use the '{}' What are the '{}' for? Thanx again!

Comment: @dkmojo {$variable} is the proper way to use variables in "strings" to maintain full control and avoid unwanted characters parsed. (Read here)[http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php]. Read **Simple Syntax** vs **Complex (curly) syntax** (search in text of linked page). (e.g.: $table = "{$wpdb->prefix}ds_entry_swoons";)

Comment: cool thanx for the insight and link. I've seen them before in plugin code but was unsure of their purpose. Now I know, and knowing is half the battle (GI JOE - had to do it) :)

Answer (score 6):

There is dedicated [`$wpdb->update()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) method that is both convenient helper to perform `UPDATE` query and performs sanitization, calling `$wpdb->prepare()` internally.

Comment: You are right @Rarst wpdb::update source: ... `return $this->query( $this->prepare( $sql, $values ) );`  : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/

Answer (score 0):

You can insert as many variables as you want (%`d`igit, %`s`tring ...)

```
global $wpdb;
$zz = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta 
    SET meta_value = '%s'       WHERE post_id = '%d'    OR WHERE post_id = '%d' ", 
                      $value,                    $id_1,                     $id_2   ) );
var_dump($zz); exit;
```